# How I can get treetable from primefaces on ManagedBean

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have used this instruction but it returns null

TreeTable treeTable = (TreeTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("form:apps");

TreeNode no = treeTable.getRowNode();

Thank's for your response

Comment: What version of primefaces are you using? How is your view and managed bean?

Comment: Hello,

I'm using the framework jsf, primefaces 5.3,